# Rendering "<%%=" with HAML

Tags: haml, erb

I have a Backbone.js application hosted in Sinatra and rendered via an ERB script. The backbone templates are using the underscore template functionality so the variables are rendered in ERB like so:

```
<div id="<%%= variable %>">
```

The extra "%" escapes the rendering of that variable and renders it with a single "%" which is what the underscore template library would pick up.

I tried the following while upgrading to HAML:

```
#"<%= id %>"
```

Which did not work. How do I accomplish the same task with HAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can’t use the `#` shortcut to create an `id` with a value like that, you’ll have to  do it the long way:

```haml
%div{:id => "<%= id %>"}
```

By default, Haml will escape the attributes, so this will produce something like:

```html
<div id='&lt;%= id %&gt;'></div>
```

which is probably not what you want. You can turn of escaping of attributes by setting the [`:escape_attrs` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options) to false. This will then produce the desired output:

```html
<div id='<%= id %>'></div>
```

Note that this option effects *all* attributes in the document.

An alternative would be to use a different set of [delimiters in your templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template). For example you could use `{{...}}` with this:

```js
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Now Haml won’t escape the attribute values.