# Haml interpolation with underscore template variable

Tags: backbone.js, haml, underscore.js

I am trying to output an underscore template variable in my haml template but I'm not having any luck.

The HTML is not being escaped so I can't seem to figure out why the underscore variable isn't rendering.

**HAML - Full Template**

```
%script{:type => "text/template", :id => "user_list_template"}
  %h4 Users
  #test
  %table.table.table-bordered
    %thead
      %tr
        %th #
        %th Name
        %th Nickname
        %th
          %tbody
          {{ _.each( users, function(user) { }}
            %tr
              %td {{= user.get('id') }}
              %td {{= user.get('name') }}
              %td {{= user.get('nickname') }}
              %td 
                %a.btn{:href => "{{= user.get('nickname') }}"}
                  View User
          {{ }); }}
```

**The source**

```
<tr>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>TacoHell</td>
  <td>TacoHelll</td>
  <td>
    <a class="btn" href="<%= user.get('nickname') %>">
      View User
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Console.log of template**

```
<h4>Users</h4>
<div id='test'></div>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nickname</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{ _.each( users, function(user) { }}
    <tr>
      <td>{{= user.get('id') }}</td>
      <td>{{= user.get('name') }}</td>
      <td>{{= user.get('nickname') }}</td>
      <td>
        <a class='btn' href="{{= user.get('nickname') }}">
          View User
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{ }); }}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have read through previously asked question but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

- [Interpolating underscore.js template with HAML](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haml/eYSx8rtk5E0/ACx4KSeWGHcJ)
- [Rendering “<%%=” with HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249252/rendering-with-haml)
- [Interpolate inside html attributes with Underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332389/interpolate-inside-html-attributes-with-underscore-js)

**Edit 1**
Added full template

**Edit 2**
console.log of template

Comment: You say they HTML is not being escaped, but then have `href="/&lt;%= user.get('nickname') %&gt;"` where the `<` and `>` _are_ escaped. Have you set the `:escape_attrs` option to false as suggested in the links?

Comment: @matt - That is an error, my mistake. They should be the actual characters.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to solve the code block issue with {{}} error that @machineghost mentioned on Jan 17 at 23:55? Or Handlebar is the answer?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a solution as it is a workaround, but one alternative would be to use a different syntax for your Underscore templates (one that doesn't involve `<` and `>`).  If you look at:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

you'll find they provide an example of alternate Django/Mustache-style template syntax:

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change
>   Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off
>   interpolated code. Define an interpolate regex to match expressions
>   that should be interpolated verbatim, an escape regex to match
>   expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an
>   evaluate regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without
>   insertion into the resulting string. You may define or omit any
>   combination of the three. For example, to perform Mustache.js style
>   templating:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name : "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

Of course, if you were considering looking in to a more powerful templating system anyway, then it certainly wouldn't hurt to abandon `_.template` and use Mustache, Handlebars, or a similar templating system instead.  But if you're happy with Underscore, the `_.templateSettings.interpolate` will let you use it without `<` or `>`.

Comment: `%tbody
      {{ _.each( users, function(user) { }}
      %tr
        %td {{= user.get('id') }}
        %td {{= user.get('name') }}
        %td {{= user.get('nickname') }}
        %td 
   %a.btn{:href => "{{= user.get('nickname') }}"}
            View User
       {{ }); }}`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) `

Comment: No worries (just FYI, you also could have edited your answer to add information like that in a "prettier" format).  As for the error, it sounds like it doesn't like your template; any chance you can paste in the template itself?

Comment: I added the full template to my OP.

Comment: Also, would it just be easier to start using Require.js and Handlebars or Mustache? I'm not to clear on how to start integrating them.

Comment: Personally I use Require + Handlebars at the company I work for, along with Alex Sexton's "HBS" plug-in (which lets you bring Handlebars templates in as Require modules).  It works great ... but switching to Require is a project in and of itself.  I'd certainly recommend it, but not as a solution for a templating problem.

Comment: As for your issue, the HAML template is great, but what's really important is the template that Underscore gets.  Any chance you could console.log it just before it goes to `_.template` and then add that to your answer?  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Like this? `users.fetch({
    success: function(users){
     var template = _.template( $('#user_list_template').html(), { users: users.models } );
     console.log(template);
     that.$el.html(template);
    }
   });`

Comment: Almost; what I'm really looking for is `console.log(('#user_list_template').html())` (because Underscore is complaining about something it doesn't like in the template that is passed to it, and that will log what is getting passed to it).

Comment: Ok, now that I can see the template you have several clear problems.  For one, you have lots of stuff like this: `{{ _.each( users, function(user) { }}`.  In that style of templating every `{{` must be followed by a `}}` before you add a single `{` (in other words, `{{a}}` NOT `{{ } a}}`).  More importantly though, your template contains logic (`_.each`), but Underscore templates don't work that way: they ONLY do variable substitution.  If you need logic in your templates, you really should look at a more robust templating solution like Handlebars.